# nmap xml file has only one row

Tags: nmap

I'm using Zenmap to discover some hosts. I save the scan as an nmap xml file. Then I import the xml file into excel to view the data.

There are thousands of rows of output in the Zenmap console, but only one row in the xml file.

I viewed the xml file in xml notepad and I can see everything. So this may be more of an excel question than an nmap question.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was an excel thing. When importing, click on the hosts column where it says "table" and then use the two arrows button to expand the table.